# Serializing js objects methods: is it really a problem

Tags: javascript, ajax

Someone says here that it would open to attack
[How do you serialize javascript objects with methods using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109769/how-do-you-serialize-javascript-objects-with-methods-using-json)

This is a rather superficial answer for me because why would it would more open to attack than  classical ajax call ? Is the guy just against Ajax ?

It's not about transmitting code to be executed to the server, it's about transmitting code to the client and it's in javascript I can't see how it's more dangerous than ajax since ajax is just doing that but statically instead of dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Transmitting code which will be evaluated from the client to the server introduces an attack vector because client-side code can be changed by a malicious user. The danger isn't that the wrong kind of data is being transmitted, but that untrustworthy programs are being *executed*. It has nothing to do with being for or against Ajax.

Comment: It's not about transmitting code to be executed to the server, it's about transmitting code to the client and it's in javascript I can't see how it's more dangerous than ajax since ajax is just doing that but statically instead of dynamically.

Comment: @user310291, huh? Staale wrote, "If you intend to run the code serverside, you open yourself to attacks." There is already a better means to deliver methods to a client: `<script>`